# NameError: name 'GridSearchCV' is not defined. I have done the import though : from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

Tags: python, machine-learning, svm, nameerror, gridsearchcv

---

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\VAISHN~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_6520/2922578464.py in 
3      'kernel': ['rbf']}
4
----> 5 optimal_params=GridSearchCV(
6     SVC(),
7     param_grid,

NameError: name 'GridSearchCV' is not defined
Here is my code:

```
param_grid={'C': [0.5,1,10,100],
     'gamma': ['scale',1,0.1,0.001,0.0001],
     'kernel': ['rbf']}

optimal_params=GridSearchCV(
    SVC(),
    param_grid,
    cv=5,
    scoring='accuracy',
    verbose=0
)
optimal_params.fit(X_train_scaled,y_train)
print(optimal_params.best_params_)
```

Comment: Have you installed the package or imported the library in your code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There could be 3 reasons on why this is happening:

1. You haven't installed the library in your environment. You can solve this using the code below:

```sh
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
pip install -U scikit-learn
```

2. You might have it installed but you are not importing it:

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
```

**UPDATE**

3. You might have an outdated version of the scikit learn package. So just try to upgrade it

```sh
pip install --upgrade scikit-learn
```

Comment: I updated my scikit-learn version and it worked. Thanks!! On scikit-learn 1.0.2 it's working

Comment: @bla Yeah bro, some of the features in GridsearchCV class are introduced in the later versions of the package. Upvote would be sweet and welcome :D